# Comparing means

Tags: descriptive-statistics

I have 3 continuous variables: fixation index for known words, unknown words and familiar words. There seems to be a difference between them but I am confused how to compare means in a significance level. Sample size is 75, data is normally distributed. No categorical factor or independent variable Which test would fit best?

Comment: Your description of the data is confusing. It sounds like you have only *two* variables, "fixation index" and "type of word." The latter is nominal with three categories. Perhaps you could post a characteristic excerpt of your data?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking for an analysis of variance with 3 independent groups

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance

Comment: Actually not Markus, I have no factors or groups for ANOVA. Maybe Friedman or something like that, not sure though.

Comment: I thought known words, unknown words and familiar words are groups in which you always measure the same index